# Centralized security for SSIS,SSAS and SSRS

Tags: security, reporting-services, ssis, ssrs-2008, ssas

Can we create centralized security role/architecture for SSIS, SSAS and SSRS? I have referred article below,
  [Dimension Security in SSAS & SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566296/dimension-security-in-ssas-ssrs)
However, it doesn't guide about the common security platform that can be build across these services.

Comment: Where's the link to the article?

Answer (score 0):

Like the link to the other question you posted these solutions will secure your DB.

- Create active directory groups and then add those groups in the
  security on SQL server.

OR

- Add the users to the security in SQL server

Then set your datasource to use the logged in users credentials once authenticated.

Once done, you can grant permissions to the users for appropriate database objects (DB's, Stored Procs, Tables, etc.) Both solutions will add security at the SQL server level and restrict access.